# Warum misst ein Zollstock metrisch?

Tags: word-choice, history, etymology

Anders gefragt, warum heißt der Meterstab umgangssprachlich Zollstock, wobei die Einteilung in Zentimeter bzw. Millimeter erfolgt? Woher stammt der Begriff Zollstock eigentlich, gibt es eine andere Übersetzung als Yardstick?

Comment: Der Zollstock ist kein "Stock" und mißt auch keine "Zoll", der Meterstab ist auch kein richtiger Stab, mißt aber dafür Meter. Richtig heißt er *Gliedermaßstab*.

Comment: Früher waren die Zollstöcke auch in Zoll geteilt.

Comment: Anschlussfrage: Hat der Zoll vom Zollstock was zu tun mit dem Zoll an der Zollschranke?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Nein. Aber das wäre eine eigene Frage wert.

Comment: @tofro Der Meterstab war früher und ist es auch heute teilweise noch, ein Stab. Zum Beispiel in der Textilverarbeitung werden noch echte Meterstäbe verwendet, um die man dann Stoffbahnen wickelt, um deren Länge abzumessen. Zusammenklappbare Zollstöcke würden in der Situation halt einfach zusammenklappen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Nein, siehe Etymologie unter https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zoll (wobei interessanterweise die Worte schon im althochdeutschen identisch waren).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Der Name Zollstock deutet darauf hin, dass früher ein starrer Stab – ein Stock – von der Länge eines Fußes, einer Elle oder eines Klafters, der in Zoll geteilt war, entsprechend Zollstock genannt wurde.* 
(Quelle: http://www.eichamt.bremen.de/sixcms/detail.php?gsid=bremen119.c.1649.de)

Anscheinend ist Zoll zunächst nur ein Wort für eine Länge, die durch die Unterteilung einer bestimmten Längeneinheit entsteht. Auf diesem Prinzip basiert offenbar das imp. inch. Früher maß man hierzulande auch auf diese Weise, also schon vor der Einführung des metrischen Systems. Der Begriff hat sich überlebt, wobei ein Meterstab optisch dem selben Prinzip wie ein Maßband/stab etc. mit irgend einer beliebigen anderen Längeneinheit als Grundlage folgt (mehrere Striche in regelmäßigem Abstand -> jeweils ein "Zoll").